# After uninstalling service using AssemblyInstaller I can not delete .exe file

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services

I used `AssemblyInstaller` in my code to remove service after that I tried to delete .exe file.

But an error occurred saying :

> The file is used by another process.

I tried `assemblyInstaller.dispose()`
but it is not working.

```
using (AssemblyInstaller installer = new AssemblyInstaller(filepath, commandLineOptions))
{
     installer.UseNewContext = true;
     installer.Uninstall(null);
     installer.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: That is entirely normal, an assembly in .NET cannot be deleted until it is unloaded.  Which requires unloading the AppDomain in which it is used.  You almost certainly are not using AssemblyInstaller for its intended use, which is impossible to see from the code snippet.  It is normally used by InstallUtil.exe to un/install services.  Which doesn't do anything more than adding/deleting registry keys.

Comment: @Hans Passant I thought AssemblyInstaller is used for installing and uninstalling services. are u suggesting InstallUtil for this?. how can i unload appdomain from assemblyinstaller?

Comment: Yes, that's what InstallUtil.exe was meant to do.  It can't cause this problem since it terminates after doing its job, which also removes the lock on the assembly.  If you want to do this yourself, and keep the program running, then you'll have to google "c# how to unload an appdomain".

Comment: @Hans Passant thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the help from others I found that using AssemblyInstaller is causing problem. To uninstall a service we can use another methods like InstallUtil.exe or ServiceInstaller.  We can use ServiceInstaller instead of AssemblyInstaller to uninstall which will not cause this problem.

```
 ServiceInstaller ServiceInstallerObj = new ServiceInstaller();
 InstallContext Context = new InstallContext(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\uninstalllog.log", null);
 ServiceInstallerObj.Context = Context;
 ServiceInstallerObj.ServiceName = "myService";
 ServiceInstallerObj.Uninstall(null);
```

this will remove service specified name and .exe file can removed without any problem

**EDIT**

I have found that using `AppDomain` we can unload the assemby

```
var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("MyDomain");
            using (AssemblyInstaller installer = domain.CreateInstance(typeof(AssemblyInstaller).Assembly.FullName, typeof(AssemblyInstaller).FullName, false, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.CreateInstance | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.ExactBinding, null, new Object[] { servicePath, new String[] { } }, null, null, null).Unwrap() as AssemblyInstaller)
            {
                installer.UseNewContext = true;
                installer.Uninstall(null);
            }
            AppDomain.Unload(domain);
```